# Вывод превью нескольких загруженных изображений

Tags: javascript, изображения, preview

У меня есть такой код:

```
<img id="uploadPreview" style="width: auto; height: 100px;" />
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" multiple name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
    <script>
        function PreviewImage() {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                 document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
            };
        };
    </script>
```

Этот код читает загруженный файл, и выводит миниатюру. Одну. Другого способа я пока не знаю... 
Как сделать вывод нескольких миниатюр, если картинка не одна? Вообще, в идеале, сделать прикрепление фотографий хотя бы визуально, как в ВК.

Comment: скопируйте это код, кроме первой строки, замените везде `uploadImage` на `uploadImage2` и юзайте

Comment: @DNS то есть, делать две кнопки? Хотелось бы всё-таки мультизагрузку одной кнопкой сделать

Comment: Наверно поторопился... Картинка вставляется кодом `document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;`. Меняйте элемент `uploadPreview` (куда вставляетися) и `src` -  что вставляется (через  обходы,как в коде, или напрямую - имя файла). Дублируйте код и настраивайте...

Comment: @DNS вот хотелось бы и понять, как вставлять разные src? Будет ли работать src[0]., src[1] например?

Comment: @DNS oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]); этой строкой мы получаем урл первого файла и вставляем его превью

Comment: @DNS и если он загружен, вставляем изображение. Может, сделать проверку на количество загружаемых файлов? Как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: 1) src - это свойство `img`. Его как массив иметь низзя. 2) да поставьте просто `src='images/puc3.jpg'` (ну или типа того)

Comment: Понять, что и как загружается из поста не получится... С вопросами проверки загрузок и передач файлов - отдельно